# Copy,Paste text content does not work within applications running under different user privilege in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-installer, privileges, windows-server-2016, group-policy

I am installing a service through msi and an installwizard.exe is invoked while installation in which data like server IP address should be provided.I have the data that need to be provided to installwizard.exe in notepad.Here I cannot paste the contents which I copied from notepad to installwizard.exe. when I checked for users under which installwizard.exe,MSI and notepad is running,I found that msi runs under ADMINISTRATOR,installwizard.exe runs under SYSTEM user and Notepad runs under ADMINISTRATOR.After installing the product by entering the data manually to installwizard.exe,I run the same installwizard.exe under administrator and I could paste the contents that I copied from Notepad.

I tried to confirm whether the issue is with user privilege and not with installwizard.exe.I run notepad.exe instead of installwizard.exe under SYSTEM USER using PsExec.exe tool(for more info :[PSEXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).When I try to paste the contents copied from notepad which is created under administrator,I get the same issue.This occurs in **windows server 2016**.
May I know if this issue occurs due to group policy changes or by some other problems within the system.